# Is there a way to preserve unfilled areas in stabilized footage?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking

I've tracked a video, and the stabilization looks okay. However it's very shaky, so a lot of the video needs to be cropped off.

Is there a way to keep the pixels from previous frames to fill these gaps?

In other words, make the video behave as a kind of "brush" which is controlled by the camera movement?

Comment: Depending on the shot in question, you could have a layer of the same stabilzed video in the background but with a temporal offset so that instead of revealing black the previous frame shows... Even a freeze frame might work.

Comment: @cegaton That more or less like what I was thinking. All the would-be-black-areas would instead be filled with the pixels from the last frame to have covered that area. Is there any way to do this automatically?

Comment: Isn't it better to crop out the stable video and scale the result to render resolution? Have a look at TrackMatchBlend video on [2point stabalisation](https://cloud.blender.org/training/track-match-blend/videos/introduction#187) if you have blender cloud access or you can find a copy on youtube.

Comment: @sambler The problem in my case is that results in way too much video being cropped off..

Comment: Nice question. Just an idea: You could try to extend your video to a panorama with microsoft [ice](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/ice/) and stabilize it afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

You may consider to load and save / overwrite source image for the calculation for each NEXT frame:

You can make some blank files with the same name with the target output filename, and put them in the render output folder BEFORE rendering. For example, you have an image sequence of 500 frames, then you should put at least 500 image files with the same name (whatever they are, even blank) into the render output foler. then add them into VSE, put into a channel below the current sequence, set the Blend mode of the current sequence to **Alpha Over**. and one frame ahead, then render. The output images will overwrite the existing ones, and luckily the calculation for the next frame will always load from disc (not from buffer or memory). Like this:

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

**NOTE**: You have to realize that the offset between two adjacent frames is often more than 1 pixel (unless the camera moves extremely slow), so, as I tested, this idea usually isn't perfect, but works.